# Does IE8 in compatibility mode display web-pages like IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

is debugging in compatibility mode in IE8 exactly the same than debugging in IE7 ?

do the websites display exactly the same ?

So I don't need IE7 for testing if I have IE8 ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty close - but not the same, there are several subtle differences.

It all depends on your code... e.g. if your pages have no doctype e.g. you are running in quirks mode or you force quirks mode, the interpretation of `height="100%"` on an iframe is different in real-IE7 vs IE7mode in IE8.  The former is "100% of my container" the later is "100% of default height" which is about 220px.

Comment: thanks for the very good answer. I cannot risk that, I guess I'm going to install another virtual machine of my mac to have windows with IE7 (I don't trust IE Tester.. )

Comment: Yeah IE Tester is actually pretty good, but it doesn't handle popup windows well at all... which for most legacy web apps causes issues. The virtual app browsers from http://www.spoon.net/Browsers/#IE are pretty darn good. Unfortunately there isn't Mac support yet but it does work inside parallels and VM Fusion.